# Using dc motor as a sensor

Tags: sensor, dc-motor

I am thinking about an automatic blind opener/closer. In this idea I need to detect the end of blind while opening or closing to stop the motor. I don't want to use mechanical sensors on both side (for simplicity sake).

Is there a way to detect reaching to the end with motor's behavior (ie: looking for more current drawing with increased load)?

Comment: Technically motors are generators, you could maybe look for an induced voltage spike from any rebound the blinds give off when it reaches it's end.

Comment: What sort of electronics are you intending to use to drive the blind motor? Is it MCU based?

Comment: @gbulmer yes I am planning to use a mcu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result will vary with motor type. Using basic brush and commutator DC motors the stall current will exceed the run current. A well as using current it would be wise to set a maximum run time as a safety backup.

As a bling operation usually uses either a cord feed or N turns of a rod it is quite simple to fit an end of run sensor, especially with a cod where end markers can be fitted to the cord. This is liable to be a much better solution long term than motor current sensing.

Comment: I like 'N turns of rod' approach. I can run a setup routine after installation to count the N value from full closed to full open. I can say open %25 by knowing the N value. Thanks